# Finding a point that is a given percentage along a range of values

Tags: statistics, arithmetic, percentages

I am interested in finding the value associated with particular percentages (e.g $80\%$, $60\%$, etc.) along a range of values.

For example, one of the sets of values of interest goes from $2$ to $8$  (and so the value associated with $50\%$ will be $5$ since this is the midpoint between $2$ and $8$). Another example would be the set of values ranging from $3$ to $15$ (the value associated with $50\%$ of that range's value would be 9 here).

How do I come up with some formula to find $\%$ and values at $80\%$, $60\%$, $40\%$, $20\%$ and make it dynamic (so that I can plug in any range and it would give me values at those $\%$).

Thank you.

Comment: If the range runs from $a$ to $b$, you need to compute $a+{n\over 100}(b-a)$ for $n=20, 40, 60, 80$. You then need to count how many scores you have in each interval. This is usually best done with a spreadsheet.

Comment: Wow...that works. Thank you I am not using Excel but using a different software (programming) so this would be possible in that too..Thank you

Comment: Note the 50% point is the median not the mean.  You would not use the mean when asked for the 50th percentile.

Comment: Oh you are right...median not mean. 50th % is median...

Answer (score 0):

We can reduce this to a simple formula for a given range and percentage using the  result that for any interval from $a$ to $b$ and a percentage $P%$, we can find the corresponding desired values by computing $a+ \frac{P}{100}(b-a)$.

More intuitively, this can be phrased as starting at the point $a$ and finding the point that is $P$% of the way along the total length of the line. And the total length of the line is simply $b-a$ (the range), hence the formula presented above.